# Which data type to use for log entries

Tags: java, list, dictionary, logging, arraylist

We have a method that checks a bunch of xml elements against their Json equivalents.

This gives us a Boolean to describe if it matched and a String to explain which elements were compared.

We then want to write these to two log files, one which contains all the entries and another which contains just the False entries (the ones that don't match).

Preferably we want the order of the entries to remain as they were added.

I tried a LinkedHashMap but this doesn't allow more than one pass or fail (as the Boolean is the key)

But it was tempting because it made the logging method simple to write as:

```
public void writeLogFile() throws IOException{
    FileWriter standardLog = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/comparisonsStandard.csv", false);
    FileWriter failureLog = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/comparisonsFailures.csv", false);

    for (Map.Entry<Boolean,String> entry : log.entrySet()) {
        standardLog.append(entry.getKey().toString() + "," + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");

        if (entry.getKey() == false){
            failureLog.append(entry.getKey().toString() + "," + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");
        }
    }

    standardLog.close();
    failureLog.close();
}
```

The obvious problem is that the log files contain either 1 or 2 entries only instead of the hundred or so required.

What standard Java data type should we use instead?

Comment: You might use a `Map<Boolean, List<String>>`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not a standard JDK type but frequently used: [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) from guava.
It can store multiple entries for each key and when iterating using `entries()` you get a standard `Map.Entry` for each key - value pair, so in your case you would get many (true, "some string") and many (false, "other string") pairs. With `Multimap` your code wouldn't change, you would just need to create this Multimap.

Other option that you have is just a simple `ArrayList`/`LinkedList` and encapsulate your boolean, String into another type (`Pair` or `Entry`):

```
public class Pair {
    private final boolean matched;
    private final String log;

    public Pair(boolean matched, String log) {
        this.matched = matched;
        this.log = log;
    }

    public boolean isMatched() {
        return matched;
    }

    public String getLog() {
        return log;
    }

}
```

And your code would look like (assuming log is `Collection<Pair> log = new ArrayList<>()`):

```
for (Pair pair : log) {
    standardLog.append(entry.getKey().toString() + "," + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");

    if (entry.isMatched() == false){
        failureLog.append(Boolean.toString(entry.isMatched()) + "," + entry.getLog() + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any other way to do this using the standard JDK?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class for pairing a logentry with a boolean and then use some list, e.g. ArrayList. Example below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class LogWriter {

    private class LogEntry{
        public final boolean isValid;
        public final String logContent;
        public LogEntry(boolean isValid, String logContent){
            this.isValid = isValid;
            this.logContent = logContent;
        }
    }

    private List<LogEntry> logEntries = new ArrayList<LogWriter.LogEntry>();

    public void addLogEntry(String logXML, String logJSON){

        // replace this with your existing comparison
        boolean isValid = logXML.equals(logJSON);
        String logContent = logXML;

        // adding the entry
        this.logEntries.add(new LogEntry(isValid, logContent));

    }

    public void writeLogFile(){

        // ..

        for(LogEntry entry : this.logEntries){
            // log all
            System.out.println(entry.logContent);

            // log invalid
            if(!entry.isValid){
                System.out.println("invalid: "+entry.logContent);
            }
        }

        // ..


    }
}
```

Well krzyk was faster :)

Comment: I had to change everything to static and now am getting an error in the AddLogEntry method stating: 

No enclosing instance of type LogWriter is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type LogWriter (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of LogWriter

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't tell why you would need to make anything static. Also LogWriter is just the name of my sample class.